# Avoid errors when processing a log file that contains weird characters

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, character-encoding

I am developing a Python 3 script that analyses a logfile line by line.
It takes the logfile to analyse as a parameter, and processes it:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="logfile analysis")
    parser.add_argument("logfile", help="log file to analyse")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    with open(args.logfile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            (... processing ...)
```

Sometimes, though, the log files contain very weird characters.
I don't even know how to copy and paste those characters here, so here is a screenshot from a text editor:
[image: Weird characters appearing in the logs]

And in those cases, I have the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loganalysis.py", line 525, in <module>
    main()
  File "loganalysis.py", line 512, in main
    for line in f:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/codecs.py", line 300, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 2265: invalid start byte
```

How can I sanitize the content of the lines before processing them, or simply ignore them without having my script to crash?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[open](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) accepts `errors` option.

> errors is an optional string that specifies how encoding and decoding
>   errors are to be handled–this cannot be used in binary mode. A variety
>   of standard error handlers are available, though any error handling
>   name that has been registered with codecs.register_error() is also
>   valid. The standard names are:
>
> - 'strict' to raise a ValueError exception if there is an encoding error. The default value of None has the same effect.
> - 'ignore' ignores errors. Note that ignoring encoding errors can lead to data loss.
> - 'replace' causes a replacement marker (such as '?') to be inserted where there is malformed data.
> - 'surrogateescape' will represent any incorrect bytes as code points in the Unicode Private Use Area ranging from U+DC80 to U+DCFF. These
>     private code points will then be turned back into the same bytes when
>     the surrogateescape error handler is used when writing data. This is
>     useful for processing files in an unknown encoding.
> - 'xmlcharrefreplace' is only supported when writing to a file. Characters not supported by the encoding are replaced with the
>     appropriate XML character reference &#nnn;.
> - 'backslashreplace' (also only supported when writing) replaces unsupported characters with Python’s backslashed escape sequences.

Pass `errors='ignore'` to ignore encoding errors.

```
open(args.logfile, 'r', errors='ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always sanitise the strings before processing, e.g.:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="logfile analysis")
parser.add_argument("logfile", help="log file to analyse")
args = parser.parse_args()
with open(args.logfile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = repr(line)
        (... processing ...)
```

This should result in a line with any special characters represented as \xc0, etc.

Comment: Thanks Steve, the problem is that the exception is raised on the "for line in f:" line, not after.